# Affixing conduit to vertical side of stucco parapet wall?

Tags: conduit, roofing, cable-management

Need to run some conduit (likely liquid tight) across a flat roof for Starlink cable and was originally going to affix the conduit up on the parapet wall with typical cable clamps with screws but noticed on the plans that the EDM roof barrier extends up under the stucco here. The roof gets a fair amount of snow and needs shoveling from time to time in the winter which is why I wanted to put it up on the on the wall to avoid someone damaging the conduit and affixation with their shovel. However, now I am concerned about the roof barrier and water getting in under then even if I seal the cable anchor screws with silicone. Any other fixation methods to the stucco that will hold on a vertical wall with the conduit? some kind of liquid nails product? Any other thoughts?

Comment: Does the EDM run all the way to the top of the parapet? If not, just attach above it.

Comment: It runs OVER the parapet and down the other side according to the roofing plans with stucco over the top. Now whether that actually happened is another matter

Comment: So much for my idea...

Answer (score 1):

I have affixed somewhat large architectural foam pieces to home walls with foam polyurethane. such as [Tank Bond](https://www.lowes.com/pd/DAP-Tank-Bond-12-oz-Pu-Foam-Adhesive/5005862483?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-pnt-_-ggl-_-LIA_PNT_221_Glue-Adhesives-Caulk-Repair-_-5005862483-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=Cj0KCQjw1_SkBhDwARIsANbGpFv-cjSIfGLzxpqZK3H7_287ab1QXFpjB8AzoCOdkcsAXufbfGeDaYoaAgk3EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

The conduit will need to be taped with a sticky Gorilla or good Duct tape to hold it for a few hours. But once stuck...it's stuck!  Any extra can be scraped off after drying.  It is a bit messy, but will hold for years.  You can paint it after curing.

Have your tape ready. Apply a bead to the surface of the conduit you want stuck on the wall and hold while taping. It's foamy and will look like it's expanding everywhere, but it shrinks back some.

Comment: Any issues with the stucco "pulling" off its lattice work underneath.

Comment: @northernlights, I never had that happen.  It's not likely with just conduit stuck on the wall.